# HTML->AJAX->not passing value to controller

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have this HTML

```
<li class="dropdown">
<a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Select your Language<b class="caret"></b></a>
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
 <li><a href="{{URL::route('language')}}" class="choose-language" id="french" data-value="fr">Français</a></li>
<li><a href="{{URL::route('language')}}" class="choose-language" id="english" data-value="en">English</a></li> 
</ul>
```

WHICH, ON CLICKING SHOULD BE PASSING THE DATA TO THIS AJAX:

```
 <script>

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.choose-language').on('click', function()

    {
        var selectedlanguage = $(this).data('value');
        $url = '{{URL::route('languagechooser')}}';
        $.post($url, {'locale': selectedlanguage},function(data){


         }); // HERE FINISHES THE $.POST STUFF          

    }); //HERE FINISHES THE CLICK FUNCTION      

}); // HERE FINISHES THE DOCUMENT AND READY STUFF

</script>
```

And this Ajax should be passing that value to this Controller:

```
class LanguageController extends Controller {


    public function languagechooser()
    {
        \Session::set('locale', \Input::get('locale'));
         return\Redirect::back();
    }

}
```

But it is not passing the value to that controller. It gets NULL as parameter received. (because I var_dump (Session::getLocale()); and I get NULL
It is confirmed that the value gets passed to the ajax on clicking the HTML a tag, (i made a click alert and it showed it). But after that, I dont understand why the controller is not getting anything.

The routes are:

```
Route::get('language', array(
    'as'=>'language',
    'uses'=>'LanguageController@languagechooser'

));


Route::post('home', array(
    'as' =>'languagechooser',
    'uses' =>'LanguageController@languagechooser'

));
```

NOTE:

Firebug Net XHR Returns: zero requests

Comment: Have you check the post request on your browser debug console? Have you tried to var_dump the request paramenters?

Comment: Sorry, I mean the whole get request, what about the ajax sended request? Does your parameter get attached to the request?

Comment: Do you block the redirect event of the `a` tag? `$('.choose-language').on('click', function (e) { e.preventDefault(); /*Rest of the code*/}` or add on the a tag `onclick='javascript: return false;'`

Comment: For example with firebug under the console tab you can see all your ajax requests, if click on them you can see some informationlike the post parameters

Comment: Not necessary, it's better the first option (not the one on tag), because then you can redirect, that function prevents the default behaviour of an element, it means that a link will not direct to another page, however you can place some code inside the function where you can redirect, if you don't block the action the function will not be executed correctly, baically the logic should be: `click->prevent redirect->ajax function->redirect to the clicked url`

Comment: Ok, I wil investigate further, however you should(have to) prevent the link behaviour with `$('.choose-language').on('click', function (e) { e.preventDefault(); /*Rest of the code*/}` and then in the `success` function of the ajax call redirect to the url of the clicked element

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't know, I have tried on jsfiddle with this code [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/EZbCkyqw) and your default html (I'm not able to save on jsfiddle), it works,so maybe there is a problem with the url, is it encapsed inside quotes? Plus you have to retrun something, take a read at this, maybe this can help [tutorial](http://blog.laravel.in/ajax-in-laravel-user-registration/)

Comment: I have found the reason but not the solution of why. When I click on the link, the URL takes it directly to the Controller, even bypasses the Ajax code, because I have tested removing the ajax code and hardcoding locale = 'en' at the Controller and the controller does change it because it has been "touched" by the URL. So, the issue is in the route. "languagechooser" at the 'a' tag.